# Boost bind function

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I have a abstract base class A and a set of 10 derived classes. The infix operator is overloaded in all of the derived classes

```
class A{
 public:
    void printNode( std::ostream& os )
    {
           this->printNode_p();
    } 
  protected:
    virtual void printNode_p( std::ostream& os )
    {
           os << (*this);
    }
};
```

There is a container which stores the base class pointers. I want to use boost::bind function to call the overloaded infix operator in each of its derived class. I have written like this

```
std::vector<A*> m_args
....
std::ostream os;
for_each( m_args.begin(), m_args.end(), bind(&A::printNode, _1, os) );
```

What is the problem with this code? In visual studio i am getting an error like this

> error C2248:
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
>   : cannot access private member
>   declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: What is the problem you've got with this? Is it not compiling, or not doing what you want?

Comment: @Alex: I have updated the post with the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this, which works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
    virtual ~base(void) {}

    virtual void print(std::ostream& pStream) = 0;
};

struct foo : base
{
    void print(std::ostream& pStream) { pStream << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

struct bar : base
{
    void print(std::ostream& pStream) { pStream << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void)
{
    boost::ptr_vector<base> v;
    v.push_back(new foo);
    v.push_back(new bar);

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
                  boost::bind(&base::print, _1, boost::ref(std::cout)));
}
```

First off, since you're using boost you may as well use `ptr_vector` to handle memory management for you. So, that's in there.

Secondly, your error is because *streams are not copyable*; however, `boost::bind` will make a copy of all it's arguments when constructing the functor. Wrap it in a `boost::reference_wrapper` (using the `boost::ref` utility function), which is copyable. When the time comes, the wrapper will convert to the necessary type and you won't notice the difference.

(This is one of the situations `boost::ref` was made for.)

---

That all said, consider using `BOOST_FOREACH`, which in my opinion generates the cleanest code:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

int main(void)
{
    boost::ptr_vector<base> v;
    v.push_back(new foo);
    v.push_back(new bar);

    foreach (base* b, v)
    {
        v->print(std::cout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that std::ostream is not copyable. I fixed it like this

```
for_each( m_args.begin(), m_args.end(), bind(&A::printNode, _1, boost::ref(os) ) );
```

Thanks,
Gokul.